# Data reshaping in sklearn (Linear regression)

Tags: anaconda, linear-regression

input code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
data.head()

data['Density'] = data['Flow [Veh/h]'] / data['Speed [km/h]']
data = data.replace(np.nan, 1)

X = data['Density']
y = data['Speed [km/h]']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train) #HERE I GOT AN ERROR
```

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing your variable X as the following:

> X = data['Density'].values.reshape((-1, 1))

I had faced the same error, where my feature set had only one variable. The above change solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[[]]` while taking the parameters:

```
X = data[['Density']]
```